# How to make alias in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, alias

I've made a Utilities javascript "class" that performs some utility functions.

Instead of having to call `Utilities.XYZ`, I'd like to be able to do something like `#.XYZ`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#` is invalid identifier character in Javascript but you can use something else

```
var $U = Utilities;
```

this will make it possible to use `$U.XYZ`. Since `$` is used by many Javascript libraries you can use `$U` as an alias for `Utilities`. Easy to understand/remember and short to type. This is aslo more versatile than single sign identifier, because you can define several aliases each for their own longer coutnerpart:

```
$A, $B, ... $Z
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with your solution.

Comment: @Darcy: Great! It will get accepted then... (in two days or something) ;)

Answer (score 4):

`#` isn't a legal identifier, but `_` and `$` are.

```
var $ = Utilities;
```

Note that `$` is used by several libraries (including but not limited to jQuery, Prototype, and MooTools), and `_` is used by underscore.js. And of course you can always add a character or two.

The full list of valid identifier characters is in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), but essentially, an identifier may start with `$`, `_`, or any alphabetic character; and then subsequent characters may be any of those as well as digits and (in recent versions of JavaScript) accented letters in various languages.

Comment: Dang that's what I thought :(. I use jquery so I can't use $....maybe I'll go with underscore. Thanks

Comment: @Darcy: Well, you *can* use `$` with jQuery if you really want to: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ You'd just have to either use `jQuery` everywhere, or come up with your own alias (`$j` or even `$.j` if you like).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I went with Robert's suggestion of using `$U`. This works well because I have a validation class and I can use `$V` for it :)